# Getting ClassNotFoundException in java after removing class file

Tags: java, exception

I removed some class file *.class from a java project. It aims to make the whole project folder clean.
Since the project was compilable and running well, I suppose that it will run faster after I clear some *.class.

However, I got exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

> at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
>     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
>     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
>     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
>     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)

What is wrong with class loader?

Comment: So - you delete a `*.class` file, get a **Class**NotFoundException, and didn't think that perhaps the former was the cause of the latter?

Comment: Yes, of cause, I suppose that all class files are generated after compiling java files. Will try more times.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's looking for the `.class` files you removed? Does the issue go away if you put them back?

`.class` files are the executable code that the Java Virtual Machine uses to run your program. If they're not there, then the JVM cannot run your program.

Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding the project through your IDE?

Comment: thanks. I thought class file expect to be generated when I compile main java class. My trouble is it gets the mentioned exception at the first place.

Answer (score 4):

Do NOT remove the `*.class` files. Those are what Java loads to run your program!

Recompile your program and try to run it again.

Answer (score 4):

The `.class` files are what the Java Virtual Machine "executes". If you delete them, you no longer have a consistent program.

Answer (score 0):

just **select Main Tab** (with "public static void") and **Run again**:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

A common approach is to not compile your classes into the same directory that the source code lives in. Using tools like Ant or Maven, or from within your IDE, you can easily have your generated class files go to a different directory. This will help reduce the clutter.